# PhoneGap attempting to upload audio media file - works iOS, file cannot be found Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

- We have an app that records audio, making use of the PhoneGap Media API and in iOS's case the File API.
- When the user clicks the *Accept & Upload* button, the app moves that file to the server making use of PhoneGap's File.FileTransfer() method.
- Works well with iOS, Android not so much.
- When I connect my Android device to my computer and mount as a drive, I can see that the file is getting created at the root which is where it should be.
- After the audio file has been created, I'm able to play the file on my device from the location stored in the global var `fullRecordPath` which = `recording.wav`
- When I attempt to point File.FileTransfer() at that came path I'm getting Error Code = 1 which I understand is *File Not Found*

Code Handling the *Accept & Upload* tap event:

```
$('#btnAcceptUpload').live('tap',function () {

    if(isIOS){
        thisFileToUpload = fullRecordPath;
    } else {
        // thisFileToUpload = './'+fullRecordPath;          //doesn't work
        // thisFileToUpload = 'file:///'+fullRecordPath;    //doesn't work
        thisFileToUpload = fullRecordPath;                  //doesn't work
    }

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();

    msg = '';
    options.fileKey="file";

    msg += "options.fileKey = "+options.fileKey+"\n";
    options.fileName=thisFileToUpload.substr(thisFileToUpload.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

    msg += "options.fileName = "+options.fileName+"\n";
    options.mimeType='audio/wav';

    options.chunkedMode = false;

    msg += "options.mimeType = "+options.mimeType+"\n";
    msg += "thisFileToUpload = "+thisFileToUpload;

    alert(msg);

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(thisFileToUpload, "http://10.0.17.121/~email/ttmovefiles.php", fileUploadSuccess, fileUploadFailure, options);
});
```

Success Callback:

```
function fileUploadSuccess(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    alert(r.response);
}
```

Failure Callback:

```
function fileUploadFailure(error){
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
}
```

Thanks for looking.

Comment: What is fullRecordPath on Android?

Comment: Simon, for the purposes of playing the audio on the device, it's `recording.wav`.  For the purposes of uploading it's `file:///mnt/sdcard/recording.wav`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, alright.  I figured this one out.  I promise I'll come back through and tighten this one down later, but wanted to get it documented so I might end helping another.

- in iOS to create a new piece of media you have no choice, you gotta use the File api.  This same fully qualified spot in the filesystem was moved in to the same global var which the Media.play() method played nicely with... in iOS.
- Not sure why it works this way, but with Android, Media.play() doesn't like the fully qualified path passed in to it.  It just wants the filename and it apparently searches from the root.
- File.FileTransfer.upload() always wants the fully qualified path of the asset to upload, regardless iOS or Android.

To Make this work:

I used the File API to create the file that the audio Media then uses to move the recording in to.  I set 2 global vars: one for playing the audio on the device `fullRecordPath` and the other for uploading `fullUploadPath`.

Here's the function the creates the file, invokes the media API and sets the global vars that Android wants:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){

    fileSystem.root.getFile(recordFileName, {
        create: true,
        exclusive: false
    }, function(fileEntry){
        alert("---------> Android File " + recordFileName + " created at " + fileEntry.fullPath);
        fullRecordPath = recordFileName;
        fullUploadPath = fileEntry.fullPath;
        mediaVar = new Media(recordFileName, function(){
            alert("Android media created successfully");
        }, androidMediaCreateFailure, mediaStatusCallback); //of new Media
        onMediaCreated();
    }, androidMediaCreateFailure); //of getFile
}, androidMediaCreateFailure); //of requestFileSystem
```

Here's the code to play that media back

```
function playAudio() {
    var my_media = new Media(fullRecordPath,

        // success callback
        function () {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        },

        // error callback
        function (err) {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err.code);
            exposeObject(err);
        });

    my_media.play();
}
```

Here's the code to upload

```
$('#btnAcceptUpload').live('tap',function () {

    if(isIOS){
        thisfullUploadPath = fullRecordPath;
    } else {
        thisfullUploadPath = fullUploadPath;
    }

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();

    msg = '';
    options.fileKey="file";

    msg += "options.fileKey = "+options.fileKey+"\n";
    options.fileName=thisfullUploadPath.substr(thisfullUploadPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

    msg += "options.fileName = "+options.fileName+"\n";
    options.mimeType='audio/wav';

    options.chunkedMode = false;

    msg += "options.mimeType = "+options.mimeType+"\n";
    msg += "thisfullUploadPath = "+thisfullUploadPath;

    alert(msg);

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(thisfullUploadPath, "http://10.0.17.121/~email/ttmovefiles.php", fileUploadSuccess, fileUploadFailure, options);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On android you need to resolveFileSystem

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(FILEURI, function(msg){
// success call msg.fullPath
}, function(){
// FAIL
});
```